# Resultado de busca NHibernate C#

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Estou fazendo uma consulta no NHibernate, mas não estou consigo trazer o resultado desejado, quero trazer todos os meus itens da tabela arquivo que não tenham relação com uma outra tabela chamada Layouts, tentei usar um where para que ele me retornasse, mas quando chamei o método dentro da minha combo box, ela ficou vazia e conferindo no banco vi que existem 3 itens sem relação. Código abaixo.

```
public Ilist <Arquivo> ConsultaSemLayout()
{

    using (ISession session = FluentnHibernate.OpenSession())
    {
        return (from e in session.Query<Arquivo>() where e.Layout.Id == null select e).ToList();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que o que você quer fazer é mais ou menos isso:

```
RepositorioArquivo rep = new RepositorioArquivo()
IList<Arquivo> lista = rep .ConsultaSemLayout();

ComboBox.DataSource = lista ;
ComboBox.DisplayMember = "NomeArquivo";
ComboBox.ValueMember = "IdArquivo";
```